# Core Data: solve a strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, core-data, exception, exc-bad-access

I am facing a really strange problem with Core Data. Let's describe it:

#### Definitions

Let's say I have two models, `ModelA` and `ModelB`. In the data model `ModelA` has a reference to `ModelB` as a one-to-many association, and consequently `ModelB` has a one-to-one association with `ModelA`.

#### Update

When the application launches (especially at first launch), or when the user asks, I have to create or update all the `ModelB` instances for each `ModelA` instance. `ModelA` instances are predetermined. For each `ModelA` instance I have about 200 instances of `ModelB`.

I use a code like this:

```
ModelB *model = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ModelB"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
model.value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:myValue];
model.modelA = modelA; // I pass modelA as a parameter to the function
[modelA addModelBObject:model];
```

I do not persist data immediately (since I have lots of data to save), but I do it at the end of the process.

#### The error

Sometimes, and only sometimes, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error at this line:

```
model.value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:myValue];
```

Enabling the zombies, I cannot see nothing more than that stupid `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, no more info.

#### The really strange error

I tried to set that value in different ways, but nothing changed. Then, I tried to `retain` the `NSNumber`, but nothing changed. Then, finally, I tried to `retain` the model once created and I got the usual `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, but correspondingly to the creation of the model, that is to say here:

```
ModelB *model = [[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ModelB"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:context] retain];
```

#### Ideas?

Have you got any ideas on how to solve this issue? Am I doing something wrong?
By the way, this problem **apparently** does not occur if I slow things down a lot (eg. saving the context every time I create a new model), but this really slow the whole application ...

### Edit

In some rare cases I get this stack trace:

```
Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
2011-06-15 11:36:59.864 myApp[457:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x313dc64f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x34b3dc5d objc_exception_throw + 24
2   CoreFoundation                      0x313dc491 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 68
3   CoreFoundation                      0x313dc4cb +[NSException raise:format:] + 34
4   CoreFoundation                      0x31351089 -[__NSCFSet addObject:] + 152
5   CoreData                            0x35136dd9 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processPendingUpdates:] + 524
6   CoreData                            0x350f4b3d -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 724
7   CoreData                            0x351363a5 -[NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges] + 16
8   CoreData                            0x350d027f _performRunLoopAction + 126
9   CoreFoundation                      0x313b3a35 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
10  CoreFoundation                      0x313b5465 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
11  CoreFoundation                      0x313b675b __CFRunLoopRun + 854
12  CoreFoundation                      0x31346ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
13  CoreFoundation                      0x31346dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
14  GraphicsServices                    0x3658841f GSEventRunModal + 114
15  GraphicsServices                    0x365884cb GSEventRun + 62
16  UIKit                               0x368ded69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
17  UIKit                               0x368dc807 UIApplicationMain + 670
18  myApp                               0x000028cf main + 82
19  myApp                               0x00002878 start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

### Edit 2

This is the stack trace of the exception:

```
#0  0x313f1460 in __CFBasicHashAddValue ()
#1  0x3133fff8 in CFBasicHashAddValue ()
#2  0x31344162 in CFSetAddValue ()
#3  0x31351012 in -[__NSCFSet addObject:] ()
#4  0x3514211a in _PFFastMOCObjectWillChange ()
#5  0x3512ed46 in _PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex ()
#6  0x35132e7e in _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core ()
#7  0x3513316a in _svfk_2 ()
#8  0x0003b750 in -[_TassoStorico setValoreValue:] (self=0x6d97bf0, _cmd=0x49064, value_=1.02600002) at _TassoStorico.m:87
#9  0x0001b62e in -[EuriborParser(hidden) readStoricoForzato] (self=0x74200d0, _cmd=0x48ff7) at EuriborParser.m:236
#10 0x31349f02 in -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] ()
#11 0x000441c4 in -[MBProgressHUD launchExecution] (self=0x90a6ff0, _cmd=0x4b83f) at MBProgressHUD.m:482
#12 0x352b3388 in -[NSThread main] ()
#13 0x353255cc in __NSThread__main__ ()
#14 0x34e20310 in _pthread_start ()
#15 0x34e21bbc in thread_start ()
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace of crash?

Comment: Just looking for the exception to occur ...

Comment: I get not particular description in the console. Should I look for something else?

Comment: you can type `bt` in gdb console to get the *backtrace*, which is similar to what you get in a Crash Report. `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is a generic error, that just mean you accessed to a protected memory address, most of the time a released object. Backtrace can help to understand where your error occured.

Comment: If you have an `NSException` or `NSError`, looking into its `userInfo` property **often** provides more details on what precisely going on. you can look at this also with gdb console : `po [e userInfo]`

Comment: Just added a rare exception in the question. I will try to get the usual one, if possible ...

Comment: looks like you inserted in `NSManagedObjectContext` a `nil` entry... hmmm weird. Maybe probably your context should be synced earlier.

Comment: This happens at the loading of the app. The context has been recently created ... and the strange fact is that the exception occurs when I am creating a new object ... I will try to force the context to sync just at the beginning of everything.

Comment: You can see the exception's stack trace in the question (Edit 2)

Comment: look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html if you don't need the undoManager, maybe setting it to nil, would help... *- (void)processPendingChanges
This method causes changes to registered managed objects to be recorded with the undo manager.* Not a solution, a workaround.

Comment: Is `_TassoStorico.m:87` == `model.value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:myValue];` ? if not, what this line contains?

Comment: Another idea, looks like you are using `MBProgressHUD`, I guess your code is triggered from an animation callback, from memory, I think CoreData is not multi-threading safe. Try not to do this from `MBProgressHUD` or try using `performSelectorOnMainThread` maybe?

Comment: Yes, that's the line that generates the exception. Actually I am calling these methods from a separate thread, since the whole process is quite long and I need to show the user a progress status (I do this both via `MBProgressHUD` both via a custom view controller)

Comment: see my previous comment about multi-threading... Almost betting that's it :)

Comment: Ok, I will try to follow your suggestion. It will be quite long to refactor all the code to avoid multi-threading on CoreData calls, so I cannot tell you right now if this solves the problem. You could add an answer as well, to this question. I will accept it in case it solves the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CoreData is not thread-safe; looks like that's your issue try looking at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138252/core-data-multi-thread-application)

Comment: Apparently, using a separate/different `NSManagedObjectContext` in the thread solved the issue. Since it's quite random, I have to do some tests to assure it's working properly.

Comment: You can only use a context on a thread when the context was created on that thread. The normal practice is to create a second context on a background thread for intensive or slow operations and then merge the background and foreground context when the background operation completes.

Comment: What does this mean? What is an example of something which is thread-safe?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue (EA_BAD_ACCESS on [managedContext save])which was caused by a KeyValueObserver that had not been removed when it should have been.  It was quite hard to track down.  This meant that I was getting this sort of behaviour even with ARC.

Comment: I've looked everywhere and found nothing. You saved my ass!

Answer (score 4):

### Reset Your Managed Object Context After a Persistent Store Migration

I had similar issues. I also work with a couple of threads, and I use Core Data’s `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` function.

In my case the error happened right after a migration in another thread. I thought that my issues were thread-related, so I began to double-down on thread-safety in my code, but in reality a single call to `managedObjectContext.reset()` ***before*** doing any subsequent operations on objects in the managed object context solved all issues.

#### Core Data Behavior

Strangely enough `existingObjectWithID:error:` was always giving me back a reference to a non-existing object, so that I was accessing non-existent objects and receiving `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. After resetting the context the function exposed the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are redundant and possibly dangerous:

```
model.modelA = modelA; // I pass modelA as a parameter to the function
[modelA addModelBObject:model];
```

The managed object context will automatically sent the reciprocal relationship for you so there is no need to do it manually. In fact, I think it might cause a dangerous loop. You can use just one line or the other and both sides of the relationship will be automatically set. I recommend just:

```
model.modelA = modelA;
```

... because it is simpler.

Comment: I usually use only one of the two calls. This is a test I've done, but do not change the exception. The problem was the one stated by @Vincent.

Comment: You're right that it's a redundancy, but I don't think it's dangerous.
Also, did you mean "the second of these two lines is redundant"?