# Is the save: method thread-safe?

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

### In short

Can I call

```
[moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    [moc save:NULL] ;
}];
```

from different threads at the same time?

### In long

I add a crash similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355126/core-data-solve-a-strange-exc-bad-access-error), namely:

```
Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
2011-06-15 11:36:59.864 myApp[457:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

The program crashes on this command:

```
[moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    [moc save:NULL] ;
}];
```

As I launch the same process (with difference parameters) to as many threads as possible (with the help of `NSOperationQueue`), this command might be called by different threads as the same time.

**Could that be a problem? Or the method `performBlockAndWait:` already deals with that?**

I ask you the question to know if I need to create a singleton that would manage the saving to the moc.

Comment: Absolutely _no_ operation on a Managed Object Context is thread safe.

Comment: Thanks. So I gonna write this singleton.

Comment: @gnasher729 That is inaccurate.  Many of the methods on the MOC are thread safe.  `-performBlock:` and `-performBlockAndWait:` are two prime examples.  Also any call that queries the state is thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-save:` must be called from the thread/queue that created the context.

calling `-performBlockAndWait:` does avoid calling it from the wrong thread.

1. You **must** pass in a `NSError` to the `-save:` method and you need to watch the result of the `-save:` to determine if an error is occurred.  That is your singular way of knowing if an error occurred.  Passing in `NULL` is asking for trouble.
2. The error you are currently seeing is **not** caused from the save directly.  It is most likely caused because you are listening to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` somewhere else and doing something incorrect there.  Search your code for that constant and review the code associated with it.

Comment: I added some blocks to an `NSOperationQueue`. In these blocks, I was inserting data and saving. I think this is where the troubles came. Thanks for your answer.