# FMDB Wrapper VS Core Data : Which is easier to Use & Maintain?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, core-data

FMDB Wrapper VS Core Data : which is easier to use & maintain?

I am confused because FMDB is very old but still many developers are using it, while Core Data is new and is only supported by 3.0 and later sdk.

Some have said that FMDB is easy to use and some said Core Data.  Please help me so I can go in the right direction.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In regards to your "only supported by 3.0 and later sdk" comment, Apple no longer accepts applications for the App Store that target an OS version older than 3.0, so this is a non-issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have used both heavily across a lot of projects now.

FMDB is very straightforward, if you know SQL it can even be pretty easy to use.  But what you have to do through the lifecycle of an app as the data model changes is:

1. Change the data model, typically with something like Base
2. Change SQL code to reflect model changes
3. Change data objects to reflect model changes
4. Add code into app to handle case where you encounter the older
   database.

What Core Data brings to the life cycle is this:

1. Data model and objects are changed with the same action (I'm
   assuming you generate data objects with something like [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/)).
2. Easier visualization of data model.
3. Encourages easier to traverse data models by making you think about
   inverse relationships.
4. Often auto-migration is enough to transition through simple model
   changes without having to rebuild the DB from scratch.
5. Core Data offers some iCloud integration via NSManagedDocument.

The hell that Core Data puts you through is:

1. Deletion sucks, because any access of properties in a deleted object
   throws a program killing exception.
2. Background thread data access sucks, because Core Data makes it
   complex to work properly with multiple threads - you cannot for
   example use a data object you obtained from a context in one thread
   in another different thread.  So much for simply passing objects to
   background threads for work with...
3. There is so much magic swirling around your data that WHEN things go
   wrong it will be terribly frustrating trying to figure out what to
   do.
4. Core Data seems terribly fragile, things like the deleted objects throwing exceptions, using from the wrong thread throwing exceptions, validations throwing exceptions, or the whole model vanishing after what seemed like a simple change are all possibilities.

So what would I recommend?  To paraphrase the old quote about Democracy, Core Data is the worst data persistence system - except for all the others.  Even with the new definition of pain and suffering that Core Data will bring to your life, it is still less work and easier to work with than FMDB or other data persistence layers.

FMDB is more straightforward and if you are OK putting lots more time into changes and data model definition that may be OK.  But generally I would recommend people bite the bullet and use Core Data unless there is a clear reason not to.

A few quick tips:

- Never delete anything in Core Data while the UI is up and possibly
  accessing objects.
- If possible treat the database as disposable and be able to rebuild
  content, so that if automigration does not work the user can still
  run the app.
- Keep all Core Data activity on the main thread and only put in the
  background as a last resort.
- Do not under any circumstance use Core Data validations, or ever uncheck the "optional" box foray field in your entities.  Which would you rather have, a bad value slip into your model that may end up displaying funny or the app simply crashing?
- Use [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) to generate data objects from your model.  It outputs objects that are directly tied back to the model that re-generation can change, and a layer of objects sort of "above" that that start out blank but into which you can add custom logic around the data objects and will not be altered when the lower objects are regenerated.

Comment: I don't say CoreData's multithread support totally sucks. You just need to follow the written rules, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138252/

Comment: Super Answer, i am the new user of this site thats why i am not accepted this kind of answer, u just exlpain every thing in detail very help full. thank you very much

Comment: @Yuji: Even when you follow the written rules, you can sometimes get odd errors merging back into the main context - especially when you have more than one background thread adding or modifying the same entities...  Not to mention what happens when you start getting background merge notifications that crash because some third party library internally uses Core Data too.  I wouldn't exactly say it sucks, they have designed for multithreaded use - but as I said in my other point it's just a very brittle thing prone to error.

Comment: BTW, as a side note the default merge conflict policy in Core Data is yet ANOTHER exception.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some specific project requirements, I would use Core Data.  Apple is constantly improving it and has optimized it for the iPhone.

Comment: thanks for answer, i also feel that it good to use Core data.

Answer (score 0):

FMDB Wrapper is easier to set up (you can just add data into your sqlite db via FireFox plugin SQLitemanager or use another SQLITE MANAGER to fill in your database), easier to debug (you can actually view real-time what's changing in your database), easier to understand, easier to learn, easier to port (to web or Android). Core Data is a poorly designed, poorly implemented, poorly documented, super unintuitive giant kludge.

Comment: Please add an example of *how*  to set up FMDB to your answer. This feels more like a comment now.