# CoreData update problems

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My app makes updates in background thread then saves context changes.
And in main context there is a table view that works with `NSFetchedResultsController`.
For some time updates work correctly, but then exception is thrown.
To check this I've added `NSLog(@"%@", [self.controller fetchedObjects]);` to `-controllerDidChangeContent:`.
Here is what I got:

```
"<PRBattle: 0x6d30530> (entity: PRBattle; id: 0x6d319d0 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PRBattle/p2> ; data: {\n    battleId = \"-1\";\n    finishedAt = \"2012-11-06 11:37:36 +0000\";\n    opponent = \"0x6d2f730 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PROpponent/p1>\";\n    opponentScore = nil;\n    score = nil;\n    status = 4;\n})",
"<PRBattle: 0x6d306f0> (entity: PRBattle; id: 0x6d319f0 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PRBattle/p1> ; data: {\n    battleId = \"-1\";\n    finishedAt = \"2012-11-06 11:37:36 +0000\";\n    opponent = \"0x6d2ddb0 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PROpponent/p3>\";\n    opponentScore = nil;\n    score = nil;\n    status = 4;\n})",
"<PRBattle: 0x6d30830> (entity: PRBattle; id: 0x6d31650 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PRBattle/p11> ; data: <fault>)",
"<PRBattle: 0x6d306b0> (entity: PRBattle; id: 0x6d319e0 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PRBattle/p5> ; data: {\n    battleId = 325;\n    finishedAt = nil;\n    opponent = \"0x6d2f730 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PROpponent/p1>\";\n    opponentScore = 91;\n    score = 59;\n    status = 3;\n})",
"<PRBattle: 0x6d30730> (entity: PRBattle; id: 0x6d31a00 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PRBattle/p6> ; data: {\n    battleId = 323;\n    finishedAt = nil;\n    opponent = \"0x6d2ddb0 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PROpponent/p3>\";\n    opponentScore = 0;\n    score = 0;\n    status = 3;\n})",
"<PRBattle: 0x6d307b0> (entity: PRBattle; id: 0x6d31630 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PRBattle/p9> ; data: {\n    battleId = 370;\n    finishedAt = \"2012-11-06 14:24:14 +0000\";\n    opponent = \"0x79a8e90 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PROpponent/p2>\";\n    opponentScore = 180;\n    score = 180;\n    status = 4;\n})",
"<PRBattle: 0x6d307f0> (entity: PRBattle; id: 0x6d31640 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PRBattle/p10> ; data: {\n    battleId = 309;\n    finishedAt = \"2012-11-02 01:19:27 +0000\";\n    opponent = \"0x79a8e90 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PROpponent/p2>\";\n    opponentScore = 120;\n    score = 240;\n    status = 4;\n})",
"<PRBattle: 0x6d30770> (entity: PRBattle; id: 0x6d31620 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PRBattle/p7> ; data: {\n    battleId = 315;\n    finishedAt = \"2012-11-02 02:26:24 +0000\";\n    opponent = \"0x79a8e90 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PROpponent/p2>\";\n    opponentScore = 119;\n    score = 179;\n    status = 4;\n})"
```

)

Faulted object (0xe972610) here causes crash. I've logged data during update & before saving. This object is in `updatedObjects` only. Why can this method return "bad" object?
(Moreover, during updates this object is affected almost each update. And only after some passes becomes "bad" one).

P.S.: I use RestKit to manage CoreData.

**UPDATE2:**

Looks like the problem is in `[self.controller fetchedObjects]` enumeration. It is called from `- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller` and seems these objects are modified even during this method call (I mean CoreData update wasn't finished to that point). Is it possible?

**UPDATED:**

The exception was got, when I did smth. like this:

```
for (PRBattle *battle in [self.controller fetchedObjects) {
    switch (battle.statusScalar) {
        case ...
        default:
            [battle willAccessValueForKey:nil];
            NSAssert1(NO, @"Unexpected battle status found: %@", battle);
    }
}
```

The exception is on line with `-willAccessValueForKey:`. Scalar status for battle is enum, that is bind to integer values 1..4. I've mentioned all possible values in switch's cases (above `default:`). And the last one has `break;`. So this one is possible only when `battle.statusScalar` returns non-enum value.

Status scalar implementation in `PRBattle`:

```
- (PRBattleStatuses)statusScalar
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"statusScalar"];
    PRBattleStatuses result = (PRBattleStatuses)[self.status integerValue];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"statusScalar"];
    return result;
}
```

And `battle.status` has validation rules:
- min-value: 1
- max-value: 4
- default: no value

And the last thing - debug log:

```
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: throwing 0x7d33f80 (object 0xe67d2a0, a _NSCoreDataException)
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x97b401 sp=0xbfffd9b0] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(id)
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x97b401 sp=0xbfffd9b0] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x7d33f60 at 0x97b79f
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: rethrowing current exception
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x97b911 sp=0xbfffd9b0] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x9ac8b7 sp=0xbfffdc20] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x97ee80 sp=0xbfffdc40] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x361d0 sp=0xbfffdc70] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0xa701d8 sp=0xbfffde10] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(id)
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x97b911 sp=0xbfffd9b0] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: finishing handler
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x97b963 sp=0xbfffd9b0] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x9ac8b7 sp=0xbfffdc20] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x97ee80 sp=0xbfffdc40] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x361d0 sp=0xbfffdc70] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0xa701d8 sp=0xbfffde10] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(id)
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x97b963 sp=0xbfffd9b0] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x9ac8b7 sp=0xbfffdc20] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x97ee80 sp=0xbfffdc40] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x361d0 sp=0xbfffdc70] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x3656f sp=0xbfffdc70] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0xa701d8 sp=0xbfffde10] for exception 0x7d33f60
objc[4664]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x7d33f60 at 0xa701f5
2012-11-07 13:37:55.463 TestApp[4664:fb03] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x6d31650 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PRBattle/p10>' with userInfo {
    NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey =     (
        "<PRBattle: 0x6d30830> (entity: PRBattle; id: 0x6d31650 <x-coredata://882BD521-90CD-4682-B19A-000A4976E471/PRBattle/p10> ; data: <fault>)"
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you using a different NSManagedObjectContext for each thread? Look at the accepted answer at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138252/core-data-multi-thread-application

Comment: Moreover, why are you saying that object 0xe972610 is causing a crash? If you are refering to the "fault" word, it means another thing. A fault is when an object is not fully loaded in memory, it will be loaded transparently by core data only when you try to access it

Comment: What exactly is output by Core Data when the exception is thrown?

Comment: LombaX, thank you for comment. But i've read all this and conform all rules. And I thinks it causes crash not bu fault, but by working with this objects later - see my update. Tommy, thank you, and see my update too.

Comment: @kpower I see that you are using fetchedObjects to access all your fetched objects. Is it possible that the object causing the error has been deleted by other thread during your operations? From the docs of fetchedObjects method: The results array reflects the in-memory state of managed objects in the controller’s managed object context, not their state in the persistent store. **The returned array does not, however, update as managed objects are inserted, modified, or deleted.**

Comment: I thought about that. And during update I disabled deletions. Just insertion. Update is made in sole thread (there is a queue with `maxConcurrentOperations == 1`) and to the background thread, then saved.

Comment: Made some updates in question (UPDATE2). Please, check once more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crash main reason: "Saving in a Background Thread is Error-prone" (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW7). Of course, I've read this before. But the problem became bigger with RestKit. It works with "contextForCurrentThread". So you get sole context for background thread as it should be (according to the same document). But you can't save it from main thread, except when you pass it directly, cause in main thread this method returns another context. When I've seen this, I thought RestKit fixed this for me (during "normal" save, not from main thread), but no.

The second thing is `NSFetchedResultsController`. When you call `[self.controller fetchedObjects]` from `-controllerDidChangeContent:` you should be ready, that this array can be changed in time. I took this array and, making enumeration, retrieved necessary data. And during enumeration it was changed (I think, it's a `NSMutableArray` returned wity typecast to `NSArray` - so this behavior becomes possible). You will never see this in "default" behavior (when you get objects with `objectForIndexPath:` for each rendered cell - as in Apple examples), but in my app I have additional cells, except containing data objects. So I need to generate my own storage, instead of using controller's fetched results directly. And this way I will recommend to avoid using `NSFetchedResultsController` at all. I've replaced it with simple `NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotification` observer and loading data each time.

Comment: what do you mean by "the array changed"? [self.controller fetchedObjects] is a NSArray, so it won't change (means: can't add or remove objects, so the count will remain the same). But you must remember the nature of the array: a collection of objects --> if one of the object pointed by the array changes itself (imagine to point to a NSMutableString that changes from "a" to "b"), the "content" of the array changes even if it's immutable. So the problem were the two I suggested :-P problem with background management and with [self.controller fetchedObjects] ;-)

Comment: It was an error: smth like "array was changed while enumerating". And you are wrong, method that returns `NSArray` can in fact simply return `NSMutableArray` (cause `NSArray` is his parent). And while all others will "think" it is immutable - it can be changed.

Comment: And one more thing. When you enumerate through objects, you can change their parameters without any problems. Cause the pointers won't change - and you will never get any error here.

Comment: But you were closer to the result solution than others :) So thank you (and all users, who gave their suggestions)!!

Comment: About your second comment, it's exactly what I said :) if you have an immutable array the objects can still change in their content. The thing that doesn't change are the pointer to the objects (their addresses) and their count. So my question was: what changed? the count of the objects or their content? I assume the second :-) --> the object was changed/removed in the core data stack, but the fetchedObjects array was still having a reference to that object!

Comment: About the first comment: it's true, a NSMutableArray can be returned from a method that should return an NSArray without compiler warnings (the compiler is the only one that can complain in this case, because at runtime you can even return an NSPotato*, they are always pointer to memory address ;-). But this is not the case, you can try: `NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]; [array addObject:self];` //[_PFBatchFaultingArray addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance, meaning that is not a mutable array ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19627/discussion-between-kpower-and-lombax)