# iOS Access Core Data Entities while updating them in background

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, concurrency, magicalrecord

In my iOS app I am hitting a web service when the app loads to check for updates to various tables(entities) in my Core Data DB.

I do this in a background thread so the user can still interact with the app

The issue I am having is when I try to load a view that contains a table of entities that I access from Core Data-- the app becomes unresponsive and lags until the background updating is complete.

Is it possible to have a lag-less experience if for example I touch to view my table of "Tasks" while in the background I am updating those "Tasks"?

I am using MagicalRecord and performing my creates/updates in a `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` block

```
 [MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){      
        //UserTasks
        if([viewName isEqualToString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserTask_vw_iSales"] lowercaseString]])
        {
            //returns a UserTask or nil if one does not exist
            UserTask *oldUserTask = [UserTask doesExist:[record valueForKey:@"JSONData"]];

            if(oldUserTask)
            {
                NSLog(@"deleting old UserTask");

                [UserTask MR_deleteAllMatchingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userTaskUID == %@", oldUserTask.userTaskUID] inContext:localContext];
            }

            //create new one 
            UserTask *utt = [UserTask MR_createInContext:localContext];
            [utt initWithJSONSting:[record valueForKey:@"JSONData"]];

            NSLog(@"Creating UserTaskType: %@", utt.userTaskUID);
        }
 }];
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where do you initialize your `NSManagedObjectContext`? The concurrency type with which it was initialized is an important factor to consider.

Comment: @JacobRelkin In my AppDelegate I init my main NSManagedObjectContext using the line: `_managedObjectContext= [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];` Then after that I use MagicalRecord functions to access it.

Comment: Is the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance given to you within the block equal to `+[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]`?

Comment: @JacobRelkin Hmm that I am not sure-- I would assume that localContext is a separate NSManagedObjectContext as it is going to be used on a different thread other than the main thread. I could be thinking of this wrong--

Comment: Just add a simple `NSAssert` inside the block: `NSAssert(localContext == [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext], nil);`

Comment: @JacobRelkin MagicalRecord is logging out the saves.. i notice that a lot are taking place on the main thread: `[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithErrorCallback:](0x5f9ab0) -> Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x5f9ab0): *** DEFAULT ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***` While others are correctly happening on the background thread-- I am thinking this is why my UI is locking up, but I am not sure how to resolve the issue

Comment: @JacobRelkin Anything else to point me in the right direction? Sorry to bother you but I have read every article on Stack and Google about MagicalRecord as well as Core Data in multiple threads and I still cannot seem to find the best way to do what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22348/discussion-between-jacob-relkin-and-ryang)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using MagicalRecord to get the behavior I was looking for-- I followed this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11814957/480415

Now my UI is not locked up while updating entities in the background.