# Multithreaded Core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, sdk

I have a hard time figuring out how to setup Core data in the best way possible. Right now I have a singleton, containing the core data stack with one ManagedObjectContext running on the main thread. And after I have read a lot of articles & tutorials, I have been very confused. Some stats that an singleton is okay and other, stats that a singleton and one managedObjectContext on the main thread is a bad idea (is this correct?). So how do I create the core data stack most efficiently, using multiple threads **?**

Since my app is downloading and processing a lot of parsed JSON data into my core data model, I think of importing these data in the a background thread with an MOC, and showing the data using the MOC in the main thread, is this the right way to do that **?**

I have tried using Magical Record, but I think the information about this is "tool" is small and I can't seem to get my head around how to import JSON data, avoid duplicates, create relationship and such.

Thank you for the help in advance :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy of single or multi-threading your Core Data **depends on what your app is designed to do** and how much data it is keeping in Core Data (and how often it is read/written).

Using a background thread for importing data and doing some Core Data reading on the main thread works. Just be sure you have a MOC per-thread and you only access each MOC on the thread it was created on! The merging functionality for Core Data (such as `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`) is very useful.

Some useful info in this question and the accepted answer:

[Core Data multi thread application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138252/core-data-multi-thread-application)

Answer (score 1):

Better create two `NSManagedObjectContext`. One for reading from core data and updating user interface another one is writing records into core data. It will avoid conflicts while using Main thread and background thread

Answer (score 1):

singleton is ok if you lock it.

two are ok, but you will want to use the same backing store, and observe the changes on the write context from the read context(s), then merge the changes in.