# How to store an NSData value from an URL into core data without blocking the UI?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios7

I want to store an NSData value from an URL into Core Data without blocking the UI. Please refer the code below which I am using right now, its freezing my UI for a few seconds,

```
 for (NSDictionary *data in content) {

            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ContentDetail" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID == %@ AND storeID == %@", [data objectForKey:@"id"], [data objectForKey:@"storeid"]];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
            [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
            NSError *error;

            NSArray *fetchedRecords = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

            if (![fetchedRecords count] > 0) {

                CouponDetail *couponDetail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CouponDetail" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
                NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[data objectForKey:@"couponimage"]];
                NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                couponDetail.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

                [managedObjectContext save:&error];
            }
        }
```

Comment: For that you could use threading and create a thread (not on main thread) to hit url and save ur data into core data in background. Here's a (link)[http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial] that might help in understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule your for loop on a secondary thread/queue, and this would prevent the UI from blocking. A very easy approach would be using Grand Central Dispatch, e.g.:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    <your for loop here>
});
```

You should be aware of [a few important things when using Core Data with multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138252/core-data-multi-thread-application), though.

If you want to save yourself all the hassles of doing multithreaded Core Data, have a look at [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord).

Comment: I would not recommend starting with Magical Record. As the author has stated, it is far better to understand Core Data and then use MR then to start with MR and be forced to learn two APIs at the same time.