# App freezes with core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I am working on iOS app similar to getPocket. I have news app for later read.

I am fetching all list of news in first call and saved into coredata. and  also i started downloading whole content of news and trying to save into coredata.

according to requirement we dont need pagination.

I am using this codee

```
NSDictionary *params =@{
                                @"access_token"  :str_AccessToken,
                                @"bookmark_file" :str_BookmarkFile,
                                @"alternate_id"  :str_ALTID
                                };

        //============================AFNETWORKING HEADER=========================================
        //
        //==========================AFNETWORKING HEADER==================================
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
        httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFFormURLParameterEncoding;
        [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

        //===============================SIMPLE REQUEST=====================
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                path:kGetArticleDetail
                                                          parameters:params];
        //====================================================RESPONSE
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten,long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

        }];
        // Get the data
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
            [delegate.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [self ResponseDetail:JSON];
        }
         //==================================================ERROR
                                         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation operation, NSError error) {
                                             [delegate.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                             if([operation.response statusCode] == 406){

                                                 //[SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Not Login"];
                                                 return;
                                             }

                                             if([operation.response statusCode] == 403){
                                                 NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
                                                 return;
                                             }
                                             if ([[operation error] code] == -1009) {
                                                 UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"mywebsite"
                                                                                              message:@"Please check your internet connection"
                                                                                             delegate:nil
                                                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                 [av show];
                                             }
                                             else if ([[operation error] code] == -1001) {
                                                 [self aFGetReaderDetail:str_BookmarkFile string:str_ALTID];
                                             }
                                         }];
        [operation start];
```

and core data code

```
delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context=[delegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Save_Reader" inManagedObjectContext:context];
//    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [context persistentStoreCoordinator];
//    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
//
```

My app freezes ..

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that if you are doing your downloading in the background (e.g. a multi-threaded application, which is likely the case using AFNetworking), you need to create a new managedObjectContext just for that thread doing the work.  What you're doing right now is taking the managedObjectContext which lives in your application delegate.

Instead of doing:

```
delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context=[delegate managedObjectContext];
```

do something like:

```
appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator];
// save this managedObjectContext as a property of your view controller,
// so it doesn't get released by ARC
managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
```

More information can be found [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138252/core-data-multi-thread-application).

Comment: Sir, i am new into ios. Can you please provide me some example